# angular 8 when i change the main object the filter pipe does not update

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

i am using filter in the pipe for an array

```
 *ngFor="let device of devices|filter: ['Department', departmentsFilter] |filter:['Name', searchName]; let i = index "
```

when i filter  and then change the index of the devices for example `this.devices[i] = obj` i don't see the change until i write something in the filter(filter again) or unfilter (filter textbox is empty)

any ideas how i can make filtered result show the change i made on the main object `this.devices`

Answer (score 1):

`this.devices[i] = obj` will not be reflect as a change in `this.devices` hence the solution will be to use something like the below

Below is a statement from the angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/pipes

> The reason Angular ignores the changed array element is that the reference to the array hasn't changed. Since the array is the same, Angular does not update the display.

```
  this.devices[i] = obj
  this.devices = [...this.devices];
```

with the above change detection will kick in and update the ui

Comment: i had a syntax error {....., [i]: obj} telling me it expect "," (maybe i need to update something?) so i changed this.devices = [...this.devices] and it worked like a charm, Many thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, the syntax i provided earlier works for objects `this.devices = {...this.devices, [i]: obj};